# how to change the text color of javascript comment in vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, comments

How can i Change the color of a javascript comment in Visual Studio Code Editor?
the default Color is not very visible in my Eye
im using Theme Color Of (Dark Visual Studio)
the Comment Is the text I only want to change How?

[image]

as you can see the default color dont want you to see it its hiding the word

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer after a months of reasearch in youtube toturial and microsoft documentation and it worth it but its very complex code

open settings.json

[image]

then put this code in

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [{
            "scope": [
                "comment.line.double-slash.js",
            ],
               "settings" :
                { "foreground": "#5d8025" }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

it should be like this

[image]

Comment: Based on your first image you already knew it was called `color customization`, if you would have search here on SO you would have got an instant result of hundreds answers, or you could have read the VSC doc pages. Why post images of text, and why post useless parts of the file, the `letterspacing` is not very important for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Ctrl + Shift + P
Step 2:
Search for settings.json(user)
Step 3:
Paste the below code after the comma-

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [{
        "scope": [
            "comment.line.double-slash.js",
        ],
           "settings" :
            { "foreground": "#5d8025" }
        }
    ]
}
```

Step 4:
Make changes to the foreground color by your choice !